# Do I generate a side effect?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have the following function and want to know, if it generates a side effect:

```
  def build[F[_] : Monad : Foldable, A]
  (consumer: Consumer[String, String])(cb: Vector[KkConsumerRecord] => F[A])
  : KkConsumerThread = {
    val thread = delegate.newThread(() => {
      pool(consumer)(cb)
    })
    thread.setDaemon(true)
    KkConsumerThread(thread)
  }
```

Inside the function, I create a thread but do not start it yet. That is mean for me, I do not generate any side effect yet. Am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, it seems you *are* generating a side-effect. Think about it this way - if you call this function repeatedly you'll eventually run out of memory (either by reaching OS thread # limit or java heap size limit).

Comment: Yes, I generate a side effect but I do not start the thread yet, does it mean already a side effect? How many threads can I generate, that is not run out of memory?

Comment: Yes, it counts as a side effect. May I ask the purpose of your question? About the thread # - generally, a few thousand for *nix-based systems. You can run it on yours and see when you run out of memory. Additionally, on java, each thread uses a 512kb stack so if you have, say, 100mb max memory, 200 threads at most will cause an out of memory error due to heap space.

Comment: The purpose is, I want to start kafka consumer on seperate thread for listen incoming messages. That is why, it needs own thread.

Comment: Sounds like it should happen somewhere else. I'm not sure what this part of your code is supposed to do, but if its meant to be side-effect free, I would not suggest creating a thread here.

Answer (score 1):

You generate several side-effects here:

- starting with more or less transparent `thread.setDaemon(true)`, given that you do it only once (and it seems like no one reads `false` before you return `KkConsumerThread`)
- `delegate.newThread(` registers new thread within JVM (assuming it creates a JVM thread): http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Thread.java#393, so it might be seen in JConsole/JVisualVM/jstack as unstarted thread:

  ```
  g.addUnstarted(); //adding thread to default THread group
  ... //a lot of other global mutable stuff
  ```

See: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Thread.java#327.

So, you should be careful about thread lifecycle (if you call it too often), especially if you do some other low-level stuff.

P.S. As far as I recall, creation of new thread also assigns a call-stack immediately (before start).

Comment: So when I generate a side effect, it counts as side effect? Even when I start the thread at later time.

Comment: @zero_coding yep, all threads are kept in a "registry" with global scope, you just mutating that registry. It's not as disruptive as creating `Futures` under normal circumstances, but might become even worse if you intend to call your "function" quite often

Comment: @zero_coding I don't really remember, but I think it assigns stack as well every time you create a Thread